# How to fix this bug or something in Facebook messenger

Tags: applications, wi-fi, settings

I'm using fb messenger and all of my incoming new messages are gone. I don't know what I did, all I did to this group chat was just seen.  "For an example. Today is Wednesday, my friends chat at the group chat yesterday. But the messages that I only see if from last  week Monday. All the messages from yesterday were gone". Pls help me pls there are important messages I need to see

Answer (score 0):

Because your your text messages sms mms voicemail and all emails are being forwarded to someone you live with or close to you that has access to your cell phone that can make changes to your settings . Please don't take me as a vigalanty or some terrible person  but this happen to me for a very long time and I thought I was being ha led as . A result. Till Google and Facebook saidI was being abused.